# onLoginFailure message change in meteor

Tags: meteor, authentication

I am using accountsUIBootstrap3 in Meteor. I was trying to modify the error message which is showing up in my drop down menu if user's email already exists in db during the sign up; the text is "Email already exists.".Is there a way to change this message and how I should do it?